# Show that linear combinations and multiplications of holomorphic functions define a ring structure.

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be holomorphic functions defined respectively on neighborhoods $U_1$ and $U_2$ of $0$ on the complex plane. We say that $f_1\sim f_2$ if there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $0$ in both domains of definitions such that $f_1|U = f_2|U$.

Let $O_0$ be the set of equivalence classes. I need to show that linear combinations and multiplications of functions define a ring structure on $O_0$.

Any idea or suggestion is welcomed. Thank you!

Comment: Can you include your work? We can't help if we don't know where you're stuck.

Comment: Showing that it has a ring structure means to check each of the ring properties against the structure.  Have you looked at this?  Is there a particular property you are stuck on?

Comment: Im not sure what I need to prove exactly. Should i check each of the ring properties or is any other faster way?

Comment: There is no faster way.